# How to calculate permutation test p-value when resulting computation of permutations is a matrix of test statistics

Tags: statistical-significance, permutation-test

I am working with 2 matrices consisting of matrix 1 (xrows, ycols) and matrix 2 (yrows, zcols). My resulting computation is a matrices multiplication which results in a matrix of (xrows, zcols). I would like to determine the significance of the values of this matrix. I currently permute matrix 1 20,000 times and matrix 2 20,000 times, then for each permutation I multiply matrices and get the resulting matrix. Then I compare each cell in the resulting permuted matrices with the original and calculate a p-value using the following formula: sum(observed values < permuted values)/number of permutations.

I am wondering if this approach is correct given that for each permutation I have multiple test statistics (values in the resulting matrix).

Here is some toy data:

```
matrix1 = matrix(rnorm(300), ncol = 30, nrow = 100)
matrix2 = matrix(rnorm(200), ncol = 20, nrow = 100)
t_matrix1 = t(matrix1)
result_matrix = t_matrix1 %*% matrix2

permatr <- function(x) t(apply(t(x), 2, sample))
numperms = 10
perma = list()
permb = list()
for (i in 1:numperms){
  permutation_a = permatr(matrix1)
  perma[[i]] = permutation_a
  permutation_b = permatr(matrix2)
  permb[[i]] = permutation_b
}

results = list()
for (i in 1:length(perma)){
  m1 = perma[[i]]
  m1 = t(m1)
  m2 = permb[[i]]
  results[[i]] = m1 %*% m2
}

Boolean = list()
bool = matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(result_matrix), ncol = ncol(result_matrix))
for (i in 1:length(results)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(result_matrix)){
    for (k in 1:ncol(result_matrix)){
      perm_result = results[[i]]
      bool[j,k] = result_matrix[j,k] < perm_result[j,k]
      Boolean[[i]] = bool
}
  }}

sums = Reduce(function(x,y){x+y}, Boolean)



p_vals = sums/numperms
```

Comment: I think some code and data would be very useful here.  At the very least, consider providing a toy example in R.